# How do i properly set up a trigger?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I am pretty new to this topic. So i have this table:

```
                             Table "public.client"
          Column          |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 contact_phone            | character(11)     |           | not null | 
 status                   | character(11)     |           | not null | 
 money_spent              | real              |           | not null | 
 bonus                    | real              |           | not null | 
 client_name              | character varying |           | not null | 
 assigned_employee_number | character(11)     |           |          |
```

I want to update column "bonus" each time column "money_spent" gets updated.
These are my function and trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION client_bonus_update() RETURNS trigger AS $client_bonus_update$
    BEGIN
        NEW.bonus := NEW.money_spent * 0.1;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$client_bonus_update$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER client_bonus_update
AFTER UPDATE OF money_spent
ON client
FOR ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION client_bonus_update();
```

It does not work. Default values of columns "money_spent" and "bonus" are 0, and on update bonus does not change. How should i write the code for my function and trigger?

Comment: Why use a trigger for that use case? This seems bad style. Why not set both columns in your update command?

Comment: @JonasMetzler Requirements of my study assignment: every time client buys something, their bonus must be updated automatically via triggers

Comment: `AFTER UPDATE`, that's too late to be visible in your table, the update has finished already. You need a BEFORE trigger.

Comment: Reading the docs [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) would be a good start: *The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null.*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to update the `NEW.bonus` value **after** the update using AFTER UPDATE, though, this will not affect the updated row in the table because the update has already occurred.

What you really need to be looking into for your usecase would be the BEFORE UPDATE trigger, which lets you modify the values before they are written to the table

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION client_bonus_update()
RETURNS trigger AS $client_bonus_update$
BEGIN
    NEW.bonus := NEW.money_spent * 0.1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$client_bonus_update$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER client_before_update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE OF money_spent ON client
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION client_bonus_update();
```

This makes the trigger will calculate the new bonus value before the update is applied

Answer (score 0):

**The accepted answer is completely valid.**  

But you can take this a step further and eliminate additional code (trigger) altogether. You can *redefine* `bonus` as a `generated` column. (Providing you Postgres is v11 or greater). So

```
alter table clients 
      drop column bonus;

alter table clients 
      add column bonus real
        generated always as  (money_spent*0.1) stored;
```

Now Insert or Update will automatically calculate `bonus`. Further it cannot by itself be updated, that is be a target of `set`. Thus it cannot cannot be out-of-step with `money_spent`. Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NCtssr-H).  
The potential downside being that if you inappropriately use `select *` the order of the columns has changed. The solution to that is appropriately name your columns on `select`.

Comment: wow, that is actually very interesting, i did not know about this, thanks!

Comment: I surmised. The biggest mistake made by beginning, and sometimes experienced, developers is not knowing the capabilities of their DBMS. Now you have another tool in your toolbox.  So as time allows for you, go through the documentation there are many, many other capabilities lurking there.